# $('document').ready() function not working after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ready function not working after ajax response.Below is my code.

```
function AjaxLoaded() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'abc.php', 
  data: dataString, 
  success: function(result) {
  $('document').trigger('ready');
 }
});
}
```

But this is not working at all.Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: You *might* want to consider using [`jQuery.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/), if it's more relevant to your scenario.

Comment: Sounds like a xy problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly it should be `$(document)`, not `$('document')`, however that is moot as you cannot manually trigger the `ready` event on the document. It only fires once on page load.

If you have some code you want to run after this AJAX call completes put it in a function and call that instead.

You could use `$.holdReady()` however I would suggest not interfering with the firing of base DOM events.

Answer (score 5):

it should be

```
$(document).trigger('ready');
```

not

```
$('document').trigger('ready');
```

Still this wont work as jQuery releases all the handlers assigned to `ready` event once its been executed.

**Edit**

You can assign like

```
$(document).on('ready urmethod',function(){})
```

And call like

```
$(document).trigger('urmethod');
```

Comment: If it "won't work" - a) why are we posting it as an answer, b) why are folks upvoting it?

Comment: `'no, you cant do that'` can always be an answer

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response.I tried this but not working.

Comment: @CerlinBoss: If the OP was asking "Can this be done?" then yeah, maybe "no..." would be a suitable answer. But the OP is trying to achieve something and is looking for a solution. Rory has managed to provide a useful answer while pointing out what can't be done... I just feel your point would have sufficed as a comment

Comment: Attaching the 'ready' event handler with `.on` actually is an answer to OP's question. That makes it possible to later trigger the event manually, including the way OP wants to use it. This answer should be marked the accepted answer. See docs for jquery `.trigger`. BTW, you saved my day, Cerlin.